# How to use websocket in codeigniter to update content without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, phpwebsocket

I am working in php framework codeigniter. Now I want to update records via websocket so that information update without page refresh. I can use ajax , jquery but I need to do this via websocket. So please anyone can help how to accomplish this functionality with websocket and how to use it in codeigniter.

Comment: You could look into using a service like **[pusher](http://pusher.com/)**

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter does not have support for websockets. However, you can use an external library like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) within your CI application.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but still I am unable to setup Rachet, I've installed composer but unable to install rachet so I am unable to use it. Please help me I am really stuck here...

Comment: Just get the files under `src/` from [Ratchet's Github Repo](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet)

Comment: I am still not getting it work. I've done everything but didn't find any file name autoload.php. Can you give any small code that I can run and check what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @xbone any luck with this ? Could you help ?